# Transform a non-homogeneous differential equation to a linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to calculate the flow of the differential equation $x'' + ax' + 1 = 0$ for every value of $a$. For this, I wanted to transform the equation into a linear system and find the eigenvalues of the matrix to look at the Jordan normal form. However, I'm stuck on the first step.

I know how to transform equations of the form $x'' + ax' + bx = 0$, but I have no idea what to do with the constant $1$ here.

Comment: Change variables: $x(t) = (y(t) - t)/a$

Comment: How do I get a linear system out of this?

Comment: After the substitution we get $y''+a y'=0$